# Finding execution flow/calls to functions?

Tags: debugging, dynamic-analysis

I have a binary and I'm interested in an high level overview of how it operates. I was trying to generate a list of functions called during a particular execution, with their hierarchy, for example

```
f1 . f2                . f1 . f2
        . f3 . f4                . f6
                  . f5
```

which would mean that something like this is happening in that particular execution:

```
main {
  f1();
  f2();
  f1();
  f2();
}

f2 {
  if(something) {
    f3();
    f4();
  }
  else {
    f6();
  }
}

f4 {
  f5();
}
```

This should make it easier to find the functions I'm interested in, and how they work at an high level. I could compare the flow between different executions where I do or don't do some things which should also help me.

How would I go about doing it? What tools can I use? I'm 100% new to reverse engineering, I've been searching all day and I'm starting to feel like it doesn't actually make sense since it seems something pretty basic but I can't find any result.

Comment: that looks cool but not quite what I think i need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use windbg wt (watch and trace function to generate an execution flow)

the demo below is for the code in your query compiled in debug mode (to ensure function calls exist and not optimised away by a simple substitution)

code used for example compiled in msvcpp2ktenexp debug

```
    int  glob   = 0;
    void f1(int a)  { printf("%d ",a); glob++;}
    void f3(int a)  { printf("F3 %d ",a);}
    void f5(int a)  { printf("F5 %d ",a);}
    void f6(int a)  { printf("%d ",a);}
    void f4(int a)  { f5(5);}
    void f2(int a)  { if(glob == 8) { f3(3); f4(4); } else { f6(6); } }
    void main()     { rndrob:f1(1);f2(2);f1(1);f2(2);if(glob<10){goto rndrob;} }
dry run results 
>flowt.exe
1 6 1 6 1 6 1 6 1 6 1 6 1 6 1 F3 3 F5 5 1 6 1 6
```

windbg wt results for module flowt function main() edited to remove fluff
statistics at the end shows printf() was called 21 times f3() f4() once etc etc

**:>cdb -c "g main;wt -m flowt" flowt.exe**

```
Tracing flowt!main to return address 00411bcf
   59     0 [  0] flowt!main
   62     0 [  1]   flowt!f1
1    72     0 [  2]     MSVCR100D!printf
   65    72 [  1]   flowt!f1
   62   156 [  0] flowt!main
   61     0 [  1]   flowt!f2
   62     0 [  2]     flowt!f6
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   61     0 [  1]   flowt!f2
   62     0 [  2]     flowt!f3
F3 3    72     0 [  3]       MSVCR100D!printf
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
   64   153 [  1]   flowt!f2
    62     0 [  3]       flowt!f5
F5 5    72     0 [  4]         MSVCR100D!printf
   65    72 [  3]       flowt!f5
  141  4073 [  0] flowt!main

4214 instructions were executed in 4213 events (0 from other threads)
Function Name                               Invocations MinInst MaxInst AvgInst
MSVCR100D!printf                                     21      72      72      72
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
flowt!f1                                             10      77      77      77
flowt!f2                                             10      71      75      71
flowt!f3                                              1      74      74      74
flowt!f4                                              1      69      69      69
flowt!f5                                              1      74      74      74
flowt!f6                                              9      74      74      74
flowt!main                                            1     141     141     141
```

**Answer to Comment**

If you had followed the logic exactly calc.exe will keep on outputting
the `calls in MessageLoop Forever` until you `close calc.exe`

**windbg calc.exe**
**g calc!WinMain**

This is to `go to start of Winmain Function` (`wt traces and watches a single Function Call and its childcalls N deep` so to use wt you need to be on the start of any Function you wish to trace `g Winmain Ensures you are on the start of Function WinMain`

now do

**wt -m calc**

this will loop forever logging all the sub calls inside calc!WinMain

below is a fine grained example for calc.exe

`DoOperation is a Function in calc.exe` that does all the operations
the output below `shows how to watch and trace that function a single time` it is called

`g calc!DoOperation breaks when DoOperation is called`
`wt traces the DoOperation for one time` (will trace `one bracket open` 
if you do `3+5 and hit = it will stop tracing` it will also 
`stop tracing if you do 3+5 * because *

(multiplication finishes the first operation viz addition )`

and will print the results
`g;q is required to tell we need to continue executing after wt and quit debugging when calc.exe is closed`

```
>cdb -c "g calc!DoOperation; wt -m calc ;g;q" calc

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'g calc!DoOperation; wt -m calc ;g;q'

Tracing calc!DoOperation to return address 010035a0
    2     0 [  0] calc!DoOperation
   10     0 [  1]   calc!_EH_prolog
   20    10 [  0] calc!DoOperation
   12     0 [  1]   calc!addrat
   52     0 [  2]     calc!equnum
   36    52 [  1]   calc!addrat
   19     0 [  2]     calc!addnum
   30     0 [  3]       calc!_addnum
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createnum
  112    37 [  3]       calc!_addnum
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
  118    57 [  3]       calc!_addnum
   23   175 [  2]     calc!addnum
   41   250 [  1]   calc!addrat
   28   301 [  0] calc!DoOperation

329 instructions were executed in 328 events (0 from other threads)

Function Name                               Invocations MinInst MaxInst AvgInst
calc!DoOperation                                      1      28      28      28
calc!_EH_prolog                                       1      10      10      10
calc!_addnum                                          1     118     118     118
calc!_createnum                                       1      12      12      12
calc!_destroynum                                      1       3       3       3
calc!addnum                                           1      23      23      23
calc!addrat                                           1      41      41      41
calc!equnum                                           1      52      52      52
kernel32!LocalAlloc                                   1      25      25      25
kernel32!LocalFree                                    1      17      17      17

0 system calls were executed

quit:
```

if you find escaping quotes a bit annoying and would like to keep on tracing DoOperation several times put these commands in a text file say foo.txt and run the script with

```
cdb -c "$$>a< c:\foo.txt"  calc
```

contents of foo.txt

```
bp calc!DoOperation "bp /1 @$ra \"g\";wt -m calc"
g;
```

this sets a one shot breakpoint on the return address of DoOperation() and issues a go to tell windbg to keep on executing the target after tracing and returning from the Function DoOperation() in calc.exe

output below contains an addition and LeftShift operation trace in calc.exe

**>cdb -c "$$>a< c:\foo.txt"  calc**

```
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command '$$>a< c:\foo.txt'
Addition operation 

Tracing calc!DoOperation to return address 010035a0
    2     0 [  0] calc!DoOperation
   10     0 [  1]   calc!_EH_prolog
   18    10 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!mulrat
   14     0 [  2]     calc!zernum
   12    14 [  1]   calc!mulrat
   22     0 [  2]     calc!mulnumx
   19     0 [  3]       calc!_mulnumx
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createnum
  127    37 [  3]       calc!_mulnumx
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
  133    57 [  3]       calc!_mulnumx
   27   190 [  2]     calc!mulnumx
   17   231 [  1]   calc!mulrat
   24     0 [  2]     calc!mulnumx
   19   255 [  1]   calc!mulrat
   36     0 [  2]     calc!trimit
   23   291 [  1]   calc!mulrat
   26   324 [  0] calc!DoOperation

350 instructions were executed in 349 events (0 from other threads)

left shift operation

Tracing calc!DoOperation to return address 010035a0
    2     0 [  0] calc!DoOperation
   10     0 [  1]   calc!_EH_prolog
   26    10 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
   28    16 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    4     0 [  1]   calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  1]   calc!_createrat
   32    53 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    3     0 [  1]   calc!_destroynum
   39    56 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  1]   calc!_createnum
   59    93 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    3     0 [  1]   calc!_destroynum
   65    96 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  1]   calc!_createnum
   84   133 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  2]     calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  2]     calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
   86   204 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    4     0 [  1]   calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  1]   calc!_createrat
   89   241 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    3     0 [  1]   calc!_destroynum
   95   244 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  1]   calc!_createnum
  114   281 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    3     0 [  1]   calc!_destroynum
  120   284 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  1]   calc!_createnum
  139   321 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    8     0 [  1]   calc!lshrat
   11     0 [  2]     calc!intrat
   14     0 [  3]       calc!zernum
   17    14 [  2]     calc!intrat
   52     0 [  3]       calc!equnum
   23    66 [  2]     calc!intrat
   11    89 [  1]   calc!lshrat
   14     0 [  2]     calc!zernum
   16   103 [  1]   calc!lshrat
   10     0 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
   12     6 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
    4     0 [  3]       calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  3]       calc!_createrat
   15    43 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
    3     0 [  3]       calc!_destroynum
   21    46 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   40    83 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
    3     0 [  3]       calc!_destroynum
   45    86 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   69   123 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
   12     0 [  3]       calc!addrat
   52     0 [  4]         calc!equnum
   36    52 [  3]       calc!addrat
   19     0 [  4]         calc!addnum
   30     0 [  5]           calc!_addnum
    6     0 [  6]             calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  7]               kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  6]             calc!_createnum
  142    37 [  5]           calc!_addnum
    3     0 [  6]             calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalFree
  148    57 [  5]           calc!_addnum
   23   205 [  4]         calc!addnum
   41   280 [  3]       calc!addrat
   74   444 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
   14     0 [  3]       calc!zernum
   88   458 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
   94   529 [  2]     calc!rat_gt
   21   726 [  1]   calc!lshrat
   12     0 [  2]     calc!rattolong
   10     0 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
   12     6 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
    4     0 [  4]         calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createrat
   15    43 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   21    46 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   40    83 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   45    86 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   69   123 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
   12     0 [  4]         calc!addrat
   52     0 [  5]           calc!equnum
   36    52 [  4]         calc!addrat
   17     0 [  5]           calc!addnum
   30     0 [  6]             calc!_addnum
    6     0 [  7]               calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  8]                 kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  7]               calc!_createnum
  199    37 [  6]             calc!_addnum
    3     0 [  7]               calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  7]               kernel32!LocalFree
  205    57 [  6]             calc!_addnum
   21   262 [  5]           calc!addnum
   41   335 [  4]         calc!addrat
   74   499 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
   14     0 [  4]         calc!zernum
   88   513 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  5]           calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  5]           calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
   94   584 [  3]       calc!rat_gt
   17   678 [  2]     calc!rattolong
   10     0 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
   12     6 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
    4     0 [  4]         calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createrat
   15    43 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   21    46 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   40    83 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   45    86 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   69   123 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
   12     0 [  4]         calc!addrat
   52     0 [  5]           calc!equnum
   36    52 [  4]         calc!addrat
   17     0 [  5]           calc!addnum
   30     0 [  6]             calc!_addnum
    6     0 [  7]               calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  8]                 kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  7]               calc!_createnum
  157    37 [  6]             calc!_addnum
    3     0 [  7]               calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  7]               kernel32!LocalFree
  163    57 [  6]             calc!_addnum
   21   220 [  5]           calc!addnum
   41   293 [  4]         calc!addrat
   74   457 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
   14     0 [  4]         calc!zernum
   86   471 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  5]           calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  5]           calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  4]         calc!_destroyrat
   92   542 [  3]       calc!rat_lt
   21  1312 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
   23  1318 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    4     0 [  3]       calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  3]       calc!_createrat
   26  1355 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    3     0 [  3]       calc!_destroynum
   31  1358 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   50  1395 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    3     0 [  3]       calc!_destroynum
   55  1398 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   75  1435 [  2]     calc!rattolong
   11     0 [  3]       calc!intrat
   14     0 [  4]         calc!zernum
   17    14 [  3]       calc!intrat
   52     0 [  4]         calc!equnum
   23    66 [  3]       calc!intrat
   79  1524 [  2]     calc!rattolong
   24     0 [  3]       calc!divnumx
   82  1548 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    3     0 [  3]       calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  3]       kernel32!LocalFree
   87  1568 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  3]       calc!_createnum
  107  1605 [  2]     calc!rattolong
   28     0 [  3]       calc!numtolong
  110  1633 [  2]     calc!rattolong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
  116  1704 [  2]     calc!rattolong
   24  2546 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    6     0 [  2]     calc!_destroyrat
   26  2552 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    4     0 [  2]     calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  3]       kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  2]     calc!_createrat
   29  2589 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    3     0 [  2]     calc!_destroynum
   35  2592 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    6     0 [  2]     calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  3]       kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  2]     calc!_createnum
   55  2629 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    3     0 [  2]     calc!_destroynum
   61  2632 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    6     0 [  2]     calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  3]       kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  2]     calc!_createnum
   82  2669 [  1]   calc!lshrat
   10     0 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
    3     0 [  3]       calc!longtorat
    4     0 [  4]         calc!_createrat
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createrat
    8    37 [  3]       calc!longtorat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!longtonum
    6     0 [  5]           calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  5]           calc!_createnum
   21    37 [  4]         calc!longtonum
   12    95 [  3]       calc!longtorat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!longtonum
    6     0 [  5]           calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  5]           calc!_createnum
   21    37 [  4]         calc!longtonum
   17   153 [  3]       calc!longtorat
   21   170 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   25     0 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
   28    20 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
    6     0 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  4]         calc!_createnum
   51    57 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   27   278 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   24     0 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   30   302 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   14     0 [  4]         calc!zernum
   12    14 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   22     0 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   19     0 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
    6     0 [  6]             calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  7]               kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  6]             calc!_createnum
  127    37 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
    3     0 [  6]             calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalFree
  133    57 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
   27   190 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   17   231 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   24     0 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   19   255 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   36     0 [  4]         calc!trimit
   23   291 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   33   616 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   36     0 [  3]       calc!trimit
   35   652 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   36     0 [  3]       calc!trimit
   43   688 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   14     0 [  4]         calc!zernum
   12    14 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   22     0 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   19     0 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
    6     0 [  6]             calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  7]               kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  6]             calc!_createnum
  127    37 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
    3     0 [  6]             calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalFree
  133    57 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
   27   190 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   17   231 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   24     0 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   19   255 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   36     0 [  4]         calc!trimit
   23   291 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   46  1002 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   36     0 [  3]       calc!trimit
   48  1038 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   36     0 [  3]       calc!trimit
   57  1074 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   22     0 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   19     0 [  4]         calc!_mulnumx
    6     0 [  5]           calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  5]           calc!_createnum
  127    37 [  4]         calc!_mulnumx
    3     0 [  5]           calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
  133    57 [  4]         calc!_mulnumx
   27   190 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   63  1291 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   24     0 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   66  1315 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   14     0 [  4]         calc!zernum
   12    14 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   22     0 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   19     0 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
    6     0 [  6]             calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  7]               kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  6]             calc!_createnum
  127    37 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
    3     0 [  6]             calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalFree
  133    57 [  5]           calc!_mulnumx
   27   190 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   17   231 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   24     0 [  4]         calc!mulnumx
   19   255 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   36     0 [  4]         calc!trimit
   23   291 [  3]       calc!mulrat
   69  1629 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   36     0 [  3]       calc!trimit
   71  1665 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   36     0 [  3]       calc!trimit
   76  1701 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
    6     0 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  4]         calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  4]         kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  3]       calc!_destroyrat
   82  1772 [  2]     calc!ratpowlong
   85  4523 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    6     0 [  2]     calc!mulrat
   14     0 [  3]       calc!zernum
   12    14 [  2]     calc!mulrat
   22     0 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   19     0 [  4]         calc!_mulnumx
    6     0 [  5]           calc!_createnum
   25     0 [  6]             kernel32!LocalAlloc
   12    25 [  5]           calc!_createnum
  127    37 [  4]         calc!_mulnumx
    3     0 [  5]           calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  5]           kernel32!LocalFree
  133    57 [  4]         calc!_mulnumx
   27   190 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   17   231 [  2]     calc!mulrat
   24     0 [  3]       calc!mulnumx
   19   255 [  2]     calc!mulrat
   36     0 [  3]       calc!trimit
   23   291 [  2]     calc!mulrat
   87  4837 [  1]   calc!lshrat
    6     0 [  2]     calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  3]       calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  3]       kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  2]     calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  3]       calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  3]       kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  2]     calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  3]       kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  2]     calc!_destroyrat
   91  4908 [  1]   calc!lshrat
  144  5320 [  0] calc!DoOperation
    6     0 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  2]     calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalFree
    9    20 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
    3     0 [  2]     calc!_destroynum
   17     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalFree
   12    40 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
   17     0 [  2]     kernel32!LocalFree
   14    57 [  1]   calc!_destroyrat
  153  5391 [  0] calc!DoOperation

5544 instructions were executed in 5543 events (0 from other threads)

Function Name                               Invocations MinInst MaxInst AvgInst
calc!DoOperation                                      1     153     153     153
calc!_EH_prolog                                       1      10      10      10
calc!_addnum                                          3     148     205     172
calc!_createnum                                      26      12      12      12
calc!_createrat                                       8      12      12      12
calc!_destroynum                                     40       3       3       3
calc!_destroyrat                                     14       6      14      10
calc!_mulnumx                                         5     133     133     133
calc!addnum                                           3      21      23      21
calc!addrat                                           3      41      41      41
calc!divnumx                                          1      24      24      24
calc!equnum                                           5      52      52      52
calc!intrat                                           2      23      23      23
calc!longtonum                                        2      21      21      21
calc!longtorat                                        1      17      17      17
calc!lshrat                                           1      91      91      91
calc!mulnumx                                         12      24      51      27
calc!mulrat                                           4      23      23      23
calc!numtolong                                        1      28      28      28
calc!rat_gt                                           2      94      94      94
calc!rat_lt                                           1      92      92      92
calc!ratpowlong                                       1      82      82      82
calc!rattolong                                        1     116     116     116
calc!trimit                                          10      36      36      36
calc!zernum                                          10      14      14      14
kernel32!LocalAlloc                                  34      25      25      25
kernel32!LocalFree                                   34      17      17      17

0 system calls were executed

eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=7c800000 edx=7c97e120 esi=7c90de6e edi=00000000
eip=7c90e514 esp=0007fde8 ebp=0007fee4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
7c90e514 c3              ret
0:000> q
quit:
```

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what i need, but I need a little more help on how to use it since i have no experience in windbg. I tried loading calc.exe and doing wt -m calc just for testing it but it only outputs a couple of instructions and then start.

Comment: look at the additional details added to the answer